# Telnet client for cisco router

Tags: client, apache-commons, telnet, cisco

I am writing telnet client for cisco router using apache.commons.net.telnet. But i have problem. Here is code sample:

```java
static TelnetClient telnetClient = new TelnetClient();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    setOptionHandlers();
    telnetClient.connect("192.168.127.100");
    read();
    telnetClient.disconnect();
}

private static void setOptionHandlers() throws IOException {
    ArrayList<TelnetOptionHandler> optionHandlers = 
        new ArrayList<TelnetOptionHandler>();
    optionHandlers.add(new TerminalTypeOptionHandler("VT100", false, false, true, false));
    optionHandlers.add(new EchoOptionHandler(true, false, true, false));
    optionHandlers.add(new SuppressGAOptionHandler(true, true, true, true));
    for (TelnetOptionHandler handler : optionHandlers) {
        try {
            telnetClient.addOptionHandler(handler);
        }
        catch (InvalidTelnetOptionException e) {
            System.err.println("Error registering option handler "
                    + handler.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
    }
}

public static void write(byte[] data) throws IOException {
    telnetClient.getOutputStream().write(data);
    telnetClient.getOutputStream().flush();
}

public static void read() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Read");
    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    if((read = telnetClient.getInputStream().read(buff)) > 0) {
        System.out.println(new String(buff, 0, read));
    }
    System.out.println("read="+read);
}
```

In some cases it works correctly and shows prompt for password entering. But is other cases it works incorrectly - hangs by reading from telnet input stream. Run conditions are the same. Why do I get this situation?
If anyone has tips for writing cisco telnet client, i'll be glad to hear them!

Comment: Use `tcpdump` or other packet sniffer to find out why. It's impossible to tell from this level of code.

Comment: Can you describe the problem more precisely? Are you saying you get no output at all? Or you get some output and then it hangs? Or what?

Comment: I  have tried to use wireshark. It shows, that my router sends telnet data (prompt for password entering), but my application do not response on this packets. After triple prompt was received (new prompt is sent if timeout-error occurs), my app prints all 3 prompt and then bad-password error. I don't understand when it happens. May be case is in telnet options?

Comment: Does the `read` function *ever* return, but you call it again and it blocks? Or does it *never* return even once?

Comment: Is some cases read function returns immediately, and one prompt are shown. In other cases this function hangs some time (triple password time-out, i think) and then returns, and 3 prompts, each with 'Timeout exceeded' message and bad-password error are shown.

Comment: In the case where you have a problem, is it that `read` never returns even once for that run? Or does it return, but you call `read` again?

Comment: I call telnetClient.getInputStream().read(buff) only once. In problem case this function returns after long delay. It looks like it stores received data in internal buffer, then calls internal read-function  again and again and returns all data only after password-error receiving.

Comment: If i have no problem, telnet output is `"User Access Verification

Password: "`. In problem case telnet output is `"User Access Verification

Password:
% Password: timeout expired!
Password:
% Password: timeout expired!
Password:
% Password: timeout expired!
% Bad passwords"`

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work. But i applied this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195809/looking-for-java-telnet-emulator with `readUntil` function, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this problem every time.

The problem can be worked-around by changing your read buffer size to 1 byte.

This accounts for why the readUntil() function from [Looking for Java Telnet emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195809/looking-for-java-telnet-emulator) works, at it simply calls read() for 1 byte.

That said, does this indicate a bug in org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient?

Edit: Rolled back to an earlier version of Commons Net and the problem disappeared !