# Writing a telnet client in java - how to listen for new data?

Tags: java, sockets, client, telnet

I'm attempting to implement a Telnet client in Java, which will just get data from a telnet server.

I've been looking for ages now and have found a lot of things, but not particularly what I need - for example the apache commons client example, which seems to send a lot of commands, which is just confusing me to be honest. 
So I therefore thought it would be easier to just to write my own client which connects to the server using a socket.

```
 public class TelnetClient {
    private String host;

    public TelnetClient(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public void getData(){
        Socket s = new Socket();
        PrintWriter s_out = null;
        BufferedReader s_in = null;

        try {
            s.connect(new InetSocketAddress("www.google.com" , 80));
            System.out.println("Connected");

            //writer for socket
            s_out = new PrintWriter( s.getOutputStream(), true);
            //reader for socket
            s_in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        }

        //Host not found
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host : " + host);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Send message to server
        String message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
        s_out.println( message );

        System.out.println("Message send");

        //Get response from server
        String response;
        try {
            while ((response = s_in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println( response );
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But I cant actually test this with the server currently so Im just using google.com, however I want to change it to listen continuously for new lines of data on the server.

Basically my question is, am I going about this the wrong way - am I being naive by just using sockets to access the telnet server and am I underestimating what a telnet client/server should be, thanks for any help.

Also if anyone has any good/simple examples of a telnet client, that would be very useful!!

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code, it's impossible to read.

Comment: I fixed it for you. You should be consistent with the way you use your curly braces. And that "write a line, indent the open curly brace, indent the body, unindent the curly brace, unindent the next line" looks really strange.

Comment: Okay sure thanks. Do you have any input about the question?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195809/looking-for-java-telnet-emulator

Comment: Okay that looks like it could be semi-useful, all I want to do though is open a connection with a telnet server and listen for new data, does the client need to be that sophisticated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been holding off on answering because there are a couple different things going on here -- Google doesn't have a telnet server running on port 80, it's a web (HTTP) server. You're connecting to the webserver with your telnet client and trying to talk over HTTP with plain text. [HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) and [telnet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854) are two different protocols.

So there is a mismatch between what you want to do and what these Java telnet clients are designed to do -- namely connect to a remote shell.

Based on what you've been saying, I think you can get it done much more easily by just making an HTTP request. There's a [dead simple solution in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java):

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");
        URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Sockets are complicated stuff. [Take a look at this tutorial if you want to dig deeper in to them](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html). But they're going to be a huge pain to work with and probably not help you get what you need done.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help! Also the link you provided was very useful!